# MS Graph can't query for SharePoint data

Tags: sharepoint, graph, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to query 365 SharePoint list data from MS Graph.

I've setup the app via portal.azure.com and I gave it application permissions to everything that is required for User, Mail, Sites and Groups. I gave it permissions on the MS Graph and SharePoint sections within the permissions.

I can query for Users and their calendar information but when it comes to Sites I get the following.

[Image of Api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgsSg.png)

We have the Azure AD Premium P1 subscription for Education.

I tried using the same tenant ID, Client ID and secret in Postman and I get similar results.

I tried to query for the same data via myself logged into Graph Explorer and I get the data I'm expecting.

How can I query for the data from SharePoint via the app credentials for all sites and all data in my tenant

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Users may be unable to access multiple Microsoft 365 services, any service that leverages Azure Active Directory (AAD) may be affected. Microsoft is working on this issue actively.

[Microsoft 365 Service health status](https://status.office365.com/)

Comment: My issue started way before the incident regarding AAD.  The outage is not related.